# Is it possible to insert external variable inside javascript function variable?

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript methods ( `imports`, and `namespace`)
`imports` take a string argument( eg. `imports("com.x.y.MyClass")`) and based on `string` it create a relative path and append it to head tag as script ( `type = text/javascript`). using `imports` I can attach any javascript file of my project main page.

`namespace` can take 2 to 3 paramaters ( eg. `namespace("com.x.y", "MyClass", "google.maps.Marker")` or `namespace("com.x.y", "MyClass" )` )

if we call `var clssObj = new com.x.y.MyClass( param1, param2 )`  then it searches for function `MyClass`  and calls it if it exists.

```
imports("com.x.y.HelperClass1");
imports("com.x.y.HelperClass2");
imports("com.x.z.OtherClass");
namespace("com.x.y","MyClass","MyBaseClass").Class = function(){

var ...
..
.;
function privateFunc(){ 
   this.baseclassFunction(); \\ since Myclass is a prototype of MyBaseClass
   var otherClass = com.x.z.OtherClass();
}

this.publicFun = function(){
    privateFunc();
}; 
this.MyClass = function( param1, param2 ){
    this.base();// calling base class costructor
    var helperObj1 = com.x.y.HelperClass1();
    var helperObj2 = com.x.y.HelperClass2();
};  
};
```

Is it possible to add all imported class as `MyClass` private variable? as in Java instead of using `com.x.y.HelperClass2` we use `HelperClass2` only.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no idea what all this "imports" and "namespace" business is about.  Neither of these are JavaScript native concepts, so they must be provided by some library not named in the problem statement.

Having said that, you can easily make local variables that point to properties of objects, and in so doing, create a shorthand notation for yourself.  Ex:

```
function privateFunc(){ 
   var OtherClass = com.x.z.OtherClass;
   this.baseclassFunction(); // since Myclass is a prototype of MyBaseClass
   var otherClass = OtherClass();
}
```

Another option (in the interest of listing all that I can think of) is to use `with`:

```
function privateFunc(){ 
   this.baseclassFunction(); // since Myclass is a prototype of MyBaseClass
   with (com.x.z) {
      var otherClass = OtherClass();
   }
}
```

But `with` is generally considered **bad practice** in JavaScript.  I'm mostly listing it here to make you aware of it and to encourage you to avoid using it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for confusion. imports and namespace are my own function. and namespace use its arguments to create a function like com.x.y.MyClass = function(){} as in java com,x and y are folders. imports converts its argument com.x.y.Myclass to "javascript/x/y/MyClass.js". I am trying to create a method which help me writting code as I used to write in java. I am able to do every thing except making all imported javascript function as private variable of function of the file( eg . MyClass).